# mysqli::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known on line 14

Tags: php

how to fix this bug can anyone help me. This make my another system dont work because in this login session it says that something is not good or wrong codes need help

> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: No such host is known. in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\gradingxnew\config.php on line 14
>
> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002):
>   php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\gradingxnew\config.php on line 14
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   mysqli::connect_error() in C:\xampp\htdocs\gradingxnew\config.php:15
>   Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\gradingxnew\index.php(2): include() #1
>   {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\gradingxnew\config.php on line 15

```html
<?php
    session_start();
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "";
    $db = "grading";

 // $conn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);
 // mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die(mysql_error());
    // $conn = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
    // if(!$conn){
    //  die('Could not connect: ' .mysql_error());
    // }
   $mysqli = new mysqli('$host', '$user', '$pass');
   if (!$mysqli -> connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli -> connect_errno() . ') '
      . $mysqli -> connect_error());
   }
    mysqli_select_db($db);
?>
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to connect to an unknown hostname. Always post your code when you're asking questions about it.

Comment: remove quotes from variables inside `new mysqli`

Comment: Don't post code as images. Code is text, include it in the question itself.

Comment: Change line 14 to `$mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass);` ... lose the quotes as devpro said.

Comment: one more suggestion, keep 1 format, either OOP or procedural.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove quotes from your connection's variables, like:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass);
```

Using quotes between `'$host'`,  will cater as a new string in your example.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it - what have you changed and why?

Comment: @NicoHaase: some explanation added

Comment: thank you to all who answered it work :D